# Check if user is authenticated on every menu click

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a web app that connects to a node js server. I want to ensure that the user is authenticated on every menu item is clicked. When the user logs in I am storing the user in
`req.session.username = esUser;` and on every call to server I am checking if `if(req.session.username)`. Is this enough to keep the app secure?? Is there any other way to check if the user is authenticated before making calls to server?

Comment: You can use token based auth mechanism

Comment: Can you please give me some examples? or links?

Comment: Why do you need to authenticate user on every menu click? Just do it once and check if user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Its come from the testing team than an attacker who has the needed lower level of access  can use this to elevate their privileges and execute privileged actions or retrieve privileged data. So I am trying to fix it

Comment: And this is their proposed solution "Authorization should always be explicitly checked server-side to verify that the user making the request to view data or perform an action is authorized to do so. This may be as simple as checking that a user is authorized to view a particular page in the application or check that the user is authorized to perform an action overall. Many other more fine-grained situations may exist depending on the application context and the complexity of the business functionality."

Comment: "they" are possibly referring to the `Authorization` header in the request - which is a very common method for API request authorisation - the value of the header could be `"Bearer {token}"` - where token is perhaps a server generated session id - or a JWT token - a simple search on google should give you a wealth of information on how this is written

Comment: Following this https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/nodejs/token-based-authentication-using-json-web-token . hope this will work?